# How to pass a variable into the middle of $.ajax url with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm passing a variable from one function into another, then need that variable set into the URL for the next ajax call, I thought this would be easy but nope.

Here's my code, I removed my dev key from the end of the call.

```js
function Transmission(styleID){
    $.ajax({
     url: "https://api.edmunds.com/api/vehicle/v2/transmissions/" + styleID + "?fmt=json&api_key=REMOVED",// setting styleID number in URL with passed variable
        //force to handle it as text
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
   var json = $.parseJSON(data);
   $('#car_transmission').find("option[text=" + json.transmissionType + "]").attr("selected", true);
 }});
}
```

It's failing, but if I hard code the styleID it works just fine, all of the searches I did were to add variables to the end of the URL. Any thoughts are appreciated!!

Thank you !!!!!!
d

Comment: Have you tried inserting console.log statements in your code to ensure your styleID is set prior to your Transmission call?

Comment: It should work. Makes sure `styleID` is what it's supposed to be.

Comment: yes styleID is what it's supposed to be, before adding it to the URL, There is some type of JQuery problem with adding a variable directly in a URL but I'm not that fluent in jQuery to solve it. Thanks! d

Comment: This looks good. How does your styleId looks like? Is it an int or something else?

Comment: styleID is just a string of numbers from an ajax call on a VIN. The VIN gives me the styleID and basic info, so I then pass the styleID into this function to get more details. If iI hard code it, it's fine. d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it, I was using the wrong URL, the VIN lookup gives the StyleID, the StyleID lookup gives the transmissionID, I was calling the URL for the transmissionID API, the URL's were next to each other on the webpage for edmunds API.

So thank you everyone for trying to help!!!

The moral of the story is try not to program while tired and multitasking!! lol

d

Answer (score 0):

how about change `styleID + "?fmt=json&api_key=REMOVED"` to `styleID + "?fmt="+json&"api_key="+REMOVED`

Comment: or maybe u could try to change a fromat to pass the variables,use data rather than url to pass it . here is a demo , change ur variables to this formate                                                                                          :$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!! but still no, the problem part is the + styleID + which is passed in, it doesn't seem to want to work inside of url, but works elsewhere when testing with alert(styleID);  One option is I can pass to an invisible field and read from that + $('#car_style').val() + will work but isn't very elegant. :(